# Event on marker drag Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, events, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I created and event listener to perform a function when the user drag a marker but it's not working, could anyone help me ?

This is the event listener

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', enviarParaASP(marker));
```

And the function:

```
function enviarParaASP(marcador) {
            coordenadaASalvar = { latitude: marcador.position.d, longitude: marcador.position.e };

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'GoogleMapsGeolocation.aspx/SalvaCoordenadas',
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({'coord': coordenadaASalvar}),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) { alert("OK "); },
                failure: function (msg) { alert("Sorry!!! "); }
            });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', enviarParaASP(marker));
```

will run your function and assign the return value as the listener function (not what you want, particularly since the function doesn't have a return value, so it will be null).

The line should be:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', enviarParaASP);
```

And enviarParaASP should take a [google.maps.MouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MouseEvent) as its argument.

Comment: Thanks, I understood now btw I found another way to do what I wanted to :P

Answer (score 2):

Your callback should just be a reference to your function, not an invocation:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', enviarParaASP);
```

By invoking the function, it's only going to "fire" when it appears in your code, which is when you're trying to set up the listener.